# Qt: How to properly use QSound's play slot?

Tags: c++, qt

I have written a small woker thread to play sound in Qt which works.
The code is like:

```
Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    sound = new QSound("C:/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/warning_sound/alert.wav");
    sound->setLoops(10);
}

Worker::~Worker(){
    delete sound;
}

void Worker::process()
{

    sound->play();
}
```

The process SLOT will be triggered some where else.
However, it might be triggered multiple times. The effect I would like to have is:

1. no matter how many times the SLOT has been triggered, once it is no longer triggered any more, the sound will only be played 10 times.
2. once the SLOT is triggered and during playing the sound, the SLOT will not be triggered anymore even it receives a signal.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution, but I think it should works. Use additional `bool`. `Warning`: there are global variables in my example, I do this just for speed, avoid global variables, use it as private members for example.

Edit:

I remember your last question where I recommended you to use `QSoundEffect` if you want get more control (it has more signals and methods). So I recommend it now too, but also you can use next trick with `QSound`:

```
#include "worker.h"
#include <QSound>
#include <QDebug>

bool active;
QSound *sound;
Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    sound = new QSound("path",this);
    sound->setLoops(6);
    active = false;
}

Worker::~Worker()
{
}

void Worker::process()
{
    if(sound->isFinished())
        active = false;
    if(!active)
    {
        sound->play();
        active = true;
        qDebug() << "called";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I want is not to let the process be only triggered once. I only hope during the sound is still playing, the process SLOT will not be triggered.

Comment: Thanks...I shall read the doc more carefully, I didn't notice there is something called isFinished()...

Comment: Another question, if I set sound with setLoops(10), and I call the sound->play() 10 times, will the sound be actually played 100 times?

Comment: @Nyaruko check doc http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsound.html#play-2 It can behave different on different OS. On my it mixed for example, so sound becomes very dirty